# Android ternary operator on custom color attribute for custom view

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I want to use the ternary operator to change the color of a custom view in terms of a Boolean.
Here is my custom view

```
class AddButton(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): RelativeLayout(context, attrs) {

private var imageView: AppCompatImageView
private var textView: TextView

init {

    inflate(context, R.layout.add_button, this)

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.add_button_icon)
    textView = findViewById(R.id.add_button_text)

    val attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.AddButton)
    val iconTint = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.AddButton_iconColor, 0)

    imageView.setImageDrawable(attributes.getDrawable(R.styleable.AddButton_icon))
    textView.text = attributes.getString(R.styleable.AddButton_text)

    setIconTint(iconTint)

    attributes.recycle()
}

fun setIconTint(colorId: Int) {
    imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorId), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}

fun setText(text: String) {
    textView.text = text
}
}
```

values/attr.xml :

```
<declare-styleable name="AddButton">
    <attr name="icon" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="iconColor" format="color"/>
    <attr name="text" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

In the layout :

```
<com.my.package.ui.customview.AddButton
                    app:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
                    app:iconColor="@{selected ? @color/colorRed : @color/colorBlack}"
                    app:text="@{selected ? @string/selected : @string/not_selected}"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

It is working as expected for the app:text but when i want to do it for the iconColor i have this error :

```
Cannot find a setter for <com.my.package.ui.customview.AddButton app:iconColor> that accepts parameter type 'int'
```

For now to solve the problem, i have to change the color in the code behind by listening when the selected boolean changes and then call the setIconTint of my AddButton view.

Is there a way to change the color directly in the layout file using the ternary operator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a custom data binding adapter for your custom view. First, check out [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) for the complete document.

So, in short, you need to define a method named: `setIconColor` that accepts `iconId` and sets the icon color by the provided resource id.

But if you want to use your current method named `setIconTint`, you just need to annotate your class with:

```
@BindingMethods(value = [
BindingMethod(
    type = AddButton::class,
    attribute = "iconColor",
    method = "setIconTint")])
```

After all, I again suggest you check other variants of binding adapters in the official document.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what i want !